# Postgres: How to set check constraint during an update?

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints

One way to set a value constraint is to use a database check constraint:

```
balance integer CHECK (balance > 0)
```

Is it possible to declare the constraint during an update, for example:

```
UPDATE xx SET balance = balance + 1000 WHERE user_id=$1 CHECK balance > $2
```

And be able to do this within one query.

Comment: why don't you include it in the WHERE clause itself?

Comment: So something like this? `UPDATE xx SET balance = balance + 1000 WHERE user_id=$1 AND where balance + 1000 > $2` So how do I ensure know if it is because the user_id does not exist or the balance went below limit?

Comment: UPDATE xx SET balance = balance + 1000 WHERE user_id=$1 AND  balance + 1000 > $2

Comment: Do you want a temporary check constraint just for those rows?

Comment: @vkp My question regarding the `WHERE` clause is is there a way to return some sort of error or something if it is because the balance is wrong? For example, when the `check constraint` is violated, postgres returns an error

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [hack assert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64658/placing-an-assert-in-a-sql-server-query). For SQL Server this would be:

```
UPDATE xx
SET balance = balance + 1000
WHERE user_id=$1
 AND IIF((balance + 1000) > $2, 0, 0/0) = 0
```

This causes a division by zero error in case there is a problem. It's a big hack, but it can be useful as an inline assertion.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that is a very good solution. I would prefer to return meaningful errors (CHECK constraints returns meaningful errors)

Comment: That is understandable. In SQL Server you could invoke a custom function, maybe Postgres has something similar.